# Display multi view in android on adapterView

Tags: android

I want to make a app for pdf reader, Now ,I can read every page of pdf ,but I dont' know how to make the pages organized, I want to organize the pages when I click the right ,it presents the next page , in a contrast, click the left ,it presents the last page, in a addition, the page should display in full screen.
     Through collecting some infomation, I know maybe the `adapterView` and `adapter` can be used to , but I still don't know how to do it.
     Can you give me a idea? Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a sample of what you have tried.

Comment: if you can get text of pages as a string then just update text of TextView when click left or right.

Comment: I use the open source library Mupdf ,it provides a sample of android, but I don't understand how it make every page disply,but it use adapterview and adapter, I guess, it use adapterview like listview to display pages, but I don't know,how to make it full screen and add all pages to adapterview